# Is it possible to reset rbenv in a sub-shell

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I have a ruby script which I am using to collect information from several other source repositories.  The code looks something like this:

```
def grab_deps(repo)
  Dir.chdir(repo) do
    if system('bundle check')
      raise "#{repo} does not have all dependencies installed, run `bundle install`"
    else
      `ruby -e 'Gem.loaded_specs.keys.each{ ... }'`
    end
  end
end
```

Each of these repos has a different `.ruby-version` specified.  Unfortunately because this script runs in my shell where I've already done the `rbenv init` shell integration, those .ruby-versions are not honored, and I get version mismatches.

I have pored over the docs and Google and have not found any way of resetting the rbenv for a subshell.  Ideally I would like something like `Bundler.with_clean_env`.

I have two semi-solutions:

1. Remove the shell integration and use the rbenv command internally in the script.  This might be the most reliable, but it also is bad for my workflow since I normally want rbenv in all my shells by default.
2. Hacking the `PATH`, `RBENV_VERSION` and other vars directly in the ruby script.  I was able to at least get the sub-shell using a different ruby version this way, but it's dirty, brittle and violates rbenv internals something fierce.

I'm fairly close to giving up and making the top-level script a shell-script, but it will be quite a bit uglier than the ruby version and I would really like to get this working cleanly.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you can do it in a shell script, you can do it in Ruby. Try using `system("ruby", "-e", "...")` as the primary execution method: You don't have to deal with the shell doing crazy things, plus it doesn't require a second level of escaping. Use `ENV[...]` to set environment variables before launching commands. It's not quite clear what your desired solution is.

Comment: In a clean shell with rbenv initialized, the path is to the rbenv shims is at the head of PATH.  When I first call any shimmed ruby command (ruby, bundle, rake, etc) it is loaded from that shims directory in the path and rbenv does significant munging of the environment (editing several environment variables including adding specific ruby versions to PATH).  Obviously I can undo all these things manually, but that amounts to reverse engineering rbenv poorly.  What I want is something cleaner and less brittle.